# How to span column header over 2 columns with Kendo UI Grid Wrapper?

Tags: kendo-ui

Using the MVC Wrapper for Kendo Grid,
How can I have the column header span 2 columns?

I have 4 columns
and want a header on the 1st and 3rd column
spaning col1 and col 2, and the one on col 3 spaning col 3 an 4.

when I do it with

```
.HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { Colspan = 2 })
```

it works, but there are always 4 headers, not only 2...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a`.HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style= "display:none;" })` to the following column :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.List)
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(c => { 
        c.Bound(e => e.ID); 
        c.Bound(e => e.Nom).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { colspan = 2 }); 
        c.Bound(e => e.Nb).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style= "display:none;" }); 
    })
)
```

Comment: Greetings from Switzerland to France, the display:none; works great!

Comment: Greetings from India to France and Switzerland ,  thanx it helped!!